# HTML/JS Canvas Donut Chart How to create round strokes with overlap?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, donut-chart

I have the problem that my Donut Chart isn't working as I want it to do. I want to create a Donut Chart like this one:

[image: Example Donut Chart]

But my Donut Chart looks like this at the moment:

[image]

As you can see the strokes don't overlap in the right direction. I think this might be, because I start to draw the strokes from right to left. Instead it should draw them from left to right, so the left "rounded end" is visible not the right rounded end.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
//function to draw the donut chart, ctx = context, cx - cy = position, radius and arcwith
dmbChart(ctx, cx, cy, radius, arcwidth) {
   var tot = 0;
   var accum = 0;
   var PI = Math.PI;
   var PI2 = PI * 2;
   var offset = -PI/2;

   for(var i = 0; i < this.canvasValues.length; i++) {
     tot += this.canvasValues[i];
   }  

   //Donut Sectors Color: Draw each stroke based on the value (canvasValues) and Color (canvasColors)
   for(var i = 0; i < this.canvasValues.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineWidth = arcwidth;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, offset + PI2 * (accum/tot), offset + PI2 * ((accum + this.canvasValues[i]) / tot));
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.canvasColors[i];
    ctx.stroke(); 

    accum += this.canvasValues[i];
   }
 }
```

As you can see I get the values which are the percentages how long the each stroke should be and the color. Starting on top I draw each one from top -> right -> bottom -> left and this is the result. But how can I modify it to get the result on top?

**Edit:**
With the help of @Helder Sepulveda I created it like this now. I changed a lot of the calculations fixed some bugs which came with the changes. The only problem now is that it doesn't start to draw at the top. As you can see the green stroke should start on the top:

```js
function dmbChart(ctx, cx, cy, radius, arcwidth) { 
  var canvasValues =  [30, 5, 15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10];
  var canvasColors = ["#10dc60", "#DDDDDD", "#0cd1e8", "#ffce00", "#7044ff", "#f04141", "#ffea00", "#ee82ee"];
  ctx.lineWidth = arcwidth;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
 
  
  var accum = canvasValues.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);  

  for (var i = canvasValues.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var radians = canvasValues[i] / 100 * 360 * Math.PI / 180

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, accum, accum - radians, true);
    ctx.strokeStyle = canvasColors[i];
    ctx.stroke();    
    accum -= radians;
  }
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, accum, accum - (0.1 / 100 * 360 * Math.PI / 180), true);  
  ctx.strokeStyle = canvasColors[canvasColors.length - 1];
  ctx.stroke();
}

const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 140;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

dmbChart(ctx, 70, 70, 50, 30)
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete... what is `this.canvasValues`

Comment: ah sry missed that. Its just an array of values like `[10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]` which is the percentage of each stroke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions on `canvasValues` and `canvasColors` to show something working:

```js
function dmbChart(ctx, cx, cy, radius, arcwidth) {
  var accum = 0;
  var PI = Math.PI;
  var PI2 = PI * 2;
  var offset = -PI / 2;
  var canvasValues = [10, 10, 10]
  var canvasColors = ["red", "green", "blue"]
  var tot = canvasValues.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

  ctx.lineWidth = arcwidth;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";

  for (var i = 0; i < canvasValues.length; i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, offset + PI2 * (accum / tot), offset + PI2 * ((accum + canvasValues[i]) / tot));
    ctx.strokeStyle = canvasColors[i];
    ctx.stroke();
    accum += canvasValues[i];
  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, offset, offset);
  ctx.strokeStyle = canvasColors[0];
  ctx.stroke();
}

const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 140;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

dmbChart(ctx, 70, 70, 50, 30)
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

The idea is to draw one last "short" arc with the first value(and color) at the end of the loop

I also moved a couple of lines out of the loop:

```
  ctx.lineWidth = arcwidth;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
```

that could be set just once before the loop

---

And here is what we talked about in the comments inverting the direction

```js
function dmbChart(ctx, cx, cy, radius, arcwidth) {
  var PI = Math.PI;
  var PI2 = PI * 2;
  var offset = -PI / 2;
  var canvasValues = [10, 10, 10]
  var canvasColors = ["red", "green", "blue"]
  var tot = canvasValues.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
  var accum = tot;
  
  ctx.lineWidth = arcwidth;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";

  for (var i = canvasValues.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, offset + PI2 * (accum / tot), offset + PI2 * ((accum + canvasValues[i]) / tot));
    ctx.strokeStyle = canvasColors[i];
    ctx.stroke();    
    accum -= canvasValues[i];    
  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  p = offset + PI2 * ((tot + canvasValues[canvasValues.length-1]) / tot)
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, p, p);  
  ctx.strokeStyle = canvasColors[canvasColors.length-1];
  ctx.stroke();
}

const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 140;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

dmbChart(ctx, 70, 70, 50, 30)
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: you assumed it right. canvasValues and canvasColors are both right. This solution looks good but the only problem now is that the "overlapping" ends of each strokes are right. They should be left like in the picture. The same direction like a clock for example.

Comment: that second point is interesting... we are drawing clockwise from top right red then green that is why green overlaps red and last on loop is blue... you will have to invert the drawing order and the one that get redrawn after loop will be the last

Comment: yeah you got it. well the problem is that I try for hours to invert it but I dont know how. I cant seem to find a solution or a fix for it.

Comment: maybe  a solution would be that on every position where a new stroke starts we draw a circle of the last color to create the illusion if this like you already did on the top

Comment: the `every position where a new stroke starts we draw a circle` is an option but not optimal, I edited my answer added another snippet inverting the loop, that was pretty much all we needed `for (var i = canvasValues.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {` ... and the accumulator we now subtract instead of adding

Comment: hi one more question, why is the color red now on the bottom? the array starts with red so red should be in the blue position? :) the rest is perfect!

Comment: must be the calculations `offset + PI2 * (accum / tot)` and `offset + PI2 * ((accum + canvasValues[i]) / tot)` something might need to change there too...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/27cun4z8/2/ ... can you check this fiddle, I only changed the values and colors to my values and colors and something weird is happening. do you know why? thanks for your help!

Comment: @LukasR. you have to debug this and check your math, I can't spend hours debugging for you

Comment: If you need professional one on one assistance you should consider hiring someone, you could try: https://www.fiverr.com/search/gigs?query=javascript+canvas

Comment: No problem didnt thought my problem needs so much work. Thought it would be a small bug but it seems not. But you already helped me alot to come to a solution

Comment: Hi I fixed this problem. I updated my question now. Because I still have the problem that it doesnt start to draw at the top. If you still want to help :)

Comment: That is probably best asked on a separate question... if not this question is going to keep changing as you encounter issues